# Can't figure out what's wrong: "expected primary-expression before ')' token"

Tags: c++

It isn't liking the 2nd line of this simple code:

```
string str = "Jamin rules";
string str2(str.length()*charbits, '0');
```

The error is

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Just so you know,

```
charbits
```

is a variable I defined by

```
 #define charbits 8*sizeof(char);
```

I think that's the problem because the code works when I type in

```
 string str2(str.length()*8, '0');
```

instead. Please give me some insight into this nuance.

Comment: a `#define` is not a variable it's a substitution macro, the compiler is not required to do constant folding for macros

Comment: Avoid macros like the plague...

Comment: Also, you should know that your `charbits` won't give you the number of bits in a `char`. `sizeof(char)` will always be 1 on any platform. To get the number of bits in a `char`, include `climits` and use the `CHAR_BIT` macro.

Answer (score 8):

```
#define charbits 8*sizeof(char);
```

shouldn't end with `;`, it will be expanded as;

```
string str2(str.length()*8*sizeof(char);, '0');
```

Since sizeof(char) is defined to be 1, you could change the definition to simply;

```
#define charbits 8
```

...or as a simple constant;

```
#include <stddef.h>

const size_t charbits = 8;
```

EDIT: As @keiththompson points out below, `CHAR_BIT` in `<climits>` defines the actual number of bits per char, and is obviously more portable than hard coding to 8.

Comment: But that still assumes there are exactly 8 bits in a `char`. The macro `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<climits>`, gives you the actual number of bits in a `char`; it's guaranteed to be at least 8, and is exactly 8 in most implementations, but can be bigger.

Comment: @KeithThompson True, was just translating the existing code, `CHAR_BIT` is definitely better if the asker did not want the length of his representations to be fixed at 8.

Answer (score 2):

You are inserted a suprious semi-colon due to your definition

```
#define charbits 8*sizeof(char);
```

Remove it and you'll get rid of the error.

Event better change it to a static const rather than a #define, which is discouraged for this very reason.

```
static const size_t charbits = 8 * sizeof(char);
```

Answer (score 1):

the preprocessor replaces `charbits` with `8*sizeof(char);`
The problem is the `;` which you don't have when you replaced it manually
Thus,

`#define charbits 8*sizeof(char)`

should do the job.